# Difference between OS process and normal process?

Tags: process, operating-system

In my understanding a process is,

"an operating system level concept used to describe a set of resources (such as external code
libraries and the primary thread) and the necessary memory allocations used by a running application.
For each *.exe loaded into memory, the OS creates a separate and isolated process for use during its
lifetime." -Andrew troelsen (pro c# 2010)

so each time we start an application a process is created with its own address space which cannot be shared by other process.

recently i have read in clr via c# that,

"The CLR does, in fact, offer the ability to execute multiple managed applications in a single
OS process. Each managed application executes in an AppDomain."

this says that multiple apps can run inside a single OS process, is there a difference between OS process and the process that is started when we run an application???

can someone shed light on this please.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the primary running process is managed by the operating system. The CLR/Framework offers a completely different stack known as "application domains" that allows separate running instances of a program to be executed under the same system-level process but act as completely independent processes. Not being an expert on C#/.NET model of design, I cannot facilitate an example of where this might be useful other than scalability of large systems.

Comment: I googled and found this -->
http://www.techopedia.com/definition/5220/application-domain-net

"Application domains have the following features:
 
1.Optimum utilization of system resources by using fewer processes to execute multiple applications."

quote taken from the article....